# Cygwin, opening a file doesn't allow more commands

Tags: cygwin

When I open a file in cygwin it opens the file in my text editor, but I cant type in any new commands. to type in new commands i have to hit control-c, which closes my text editor. I hate it.

How do I type in new commands in the same cygwin tab without closing the text editor?

Bonus Points: How do i open a cygwin tab?

Edit: My bad I should have been more specific, I'm opening up sublime using the command "subl example.txt"

after I type that in cygwin doesnt take any commands since its busy keeping sublime open. I mentioned control c because thats my go to for stopping commands on bash.

Comment: How do you open file in your text editor? A command to start the editor?

Answer (score 1):

Just append an & at the end of the command and it'll run in the background, allowing for you to use the terminal and the program you just opened.

Example

```
gedit Makefile &
```

Comment: That's not going to help with a non-X11 editor. Plus, the OP's comment about Ctrl-C suggests that he is not talking about a GUI editor. Ctrl-C does copy in gedit, rather than send SIGINT.

Comment: @WarrenYoung: If it's a tty-mode editor, you can (probably) type Control-Z to suspend it and go back to the shell, then `fg` to bring it back to the foreground.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Sure, but not all. `nano` for one, which also seems not to have a way to shell out or run an external command.

Comment: @WarrenYoung: You can still suspend `nano` with Ctrl-Z.

Comment: @KeithThompson: It didn't work on two RHEL5 boxes I tried it on, but on looking into it, there is the `-z` flag. Perhaps you have turned that on, or perhaps there is also a build-time option for enabling this feature, enabled on your build of nano.

Comment: @WarrenYoung: I *hate* programs that do that. On my system (Linux Mint), it's enabled via `set suspend` in `/etc/nanorc`. You can also enable it by typing Escape Z within `nano`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a traditional text-mode editor such as `vi` or `emacs`, it is of course going to take over the entire terminal which previously was used for the command prompt.

However, a decent Unix text editor will have a way to run shell commands from within the editor.

In `vi`, you can temporarily shell out with `:sh`. On saying `exit` from that command prompt, you come back to the editor you shelled out of.

`vi` can also run a single command without shelling out via its `:!some command here` facility. As with so many things in `vi`, the [`ex`-mode](http://usevim.com/2012/09/28/vim101-history/) `!` command can be combined with other commands. One I use when building a `ChangeLog` file for a new software release is `:r !svn log -r12345:HEAD`, which gets the list of changes since revision `r12345` and inserts them into the text editor at the cursor point. Here, `:r` reads output from a command rather than from a file.

[Emacs has similar facilities](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Shell.html).

As for tabs, sorry, but the default Cygwin terminal program (mintty) does not have that feature. Some people use [`tmux`](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) or [`screen`](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) to get around that limitation. Others, such as myself, tend to rely on shell-out facilities, backed up by starting additional `mintty` windows at need.